# Autofill form to get value with AJAX at models in Django

Tags: django, ajax

Dear All need some help to get data when user input

I have html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Pencarian</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <!-- tambahkan link CSS bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <form id="searchForm">
            <div class="searchContainer form-group">
                <label for="searchText">Perbandingan ke 1</label>
                <div class="input-group rounded">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded searchText" name="searchText" placeholder="Ketik untuk perbandingan">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="button" class="close closeBtn"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var formCount = 1;
            var autocompleteList = $('<div class="autocomplete-list"></div>');
    
            $("#searchForm").on("keyup", ".searchText", function(e) {
                var searchText = $(this).val();
                var searchContainer = $(this).parent().parent();
    
                if (searchText !== "" && searchContainer.next(".searchContainer").length === 0 && formCount < 4) {
                    formCount++;
                    var newForm = $('<div class="searchContainer form-group"><label for="searchText">Perbandingan ke ' + formCount + '</label><div class="input-group rounded"><input type="text" class="form-control rounded searchText" name="searchText" autocomplete="off"><div class="input-group-append"><button type="button" class="close closeBtn"><span>&times;</span></button></div></div></div>');
                    searchContainer.after(newForm);
                    $(this).next(".closeBtn").show();
                    $(this).attr("disabled", false);
                    $(".submitBtn").remove();
                    var submitBtn = $('<button type="submit" class="submitBtn btn btn-primary btn-block">Cari</button>');
                    $("#searchForm").append(submitBtn);
    
                    // AJAX call untuk mengambil data dari database Produk
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/percobaan/",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: {
                            term: searchText 
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            var autocompleteList = $('<div class="autocomplete-list"></div>');
                            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                                var autocompleteItem = $('<div class="autocomplete-item">' + value.fields.nama_produk + '</div>');
                                autocompleteItem.on("click", function(e) {
                                    $(this).closest(".searchContainer").find(".searchText").val($(this).text());
                                    autocompleteList.remove();
                                });
                                autocompleteList.append(autocompleteItem);
                            });
                            newForm.append(autocompleteList);
                        },
                        
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
    
                }
            });
    
            $("#searchForm").on("click", ".closeBtn", function(e) {
                $(this).closest(".searchContainer").remove();
                formCount--;
    
                if (formCount === 1) {
                    $(".closeBtn").hide();
                    $(".searchText").attr("disabled", false);
                    $(".submitBtn").remove();
                } else {
                    $(".searchContainer label").each(function(index) {
                        $(this).text("Perbandingan ke " + (index + 1));
                    });
                }
            });
    
            $(document).on("click", function(e) {
                if (!$(e.target).hasClass("searchText")) {
                    autocompleteList.remove();
                }
            });
    
            $("#searchForm").on("submit", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var searchText = $(".searchText:not(:disabled)").map(function() {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get();
                // lakukan proses pencarian
                console.log("Pencarian untuk: " + searchText);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the models.py

```
class Produk(models.Model):
    nama_produk = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
def percobaan(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        produk = Produk.objects.filter(nama_produk__icontains=q)
        results = []
        for prod in produk:
            prod_json = {}
            prod_json['id'] = prod.id
            prod_json['label'] = prod.nama_produk
            prod_json['value'] = prod.nama_produk
            results.append(prod_json)
        data = {'results': results}
        return JsonResponse(data)
    data = {}
    context = {'data': data}
    return render(request, 'percobaan.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
    path('percobaan/', views.percobaan, name='percobaan'),
```

I was input the data in database before, because the expectation is...
when the user input any alphabet at the form, the form fields would showing the autofill which match value in the database

and the browser console give me the error message

```
Error: Not Found 2 percobaan:56:37
XHRGEThttp://localhost:8000/percobaan/?term=A
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 8ms]
Error: Not Found
```

**Edit :

I change the url: "/percobaan/", -> url: "{% url 'percobaan' %}"

as Nealium's advice (so thank you, appreciate your attention)
but at the console give the response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVZ9W.png)

Comment: Because you have all this Javascript in the Template, you can just use a Url Template tag and that should clear it all up.

`url: "/percobaan/",` -> `url: "{% url 'percobaan' %}",`

Comment: thank you for your reply, anyway I was tried, but still not work, but at the console give response the existing database value

Comment: `value.fields.nama_produk` -> `value.text` ..and honestly while you have it, you might as well embedd the rest as attributes on that line:
`var autocompleteItem = $('<div class="autocomplete-item" pk="'+ value.pk +'" value="' + value.value + '">' + value.text + '</div>');`

Comment: Opps! there seems to be a mismatch between your image and your code block. 
If you are still using `prod_json['label'] = prod.nama_produk` in your view, `value.text` should be `value.label` in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and your time, really appreciate, I have trying, but still not work, undefined, pribably, I had to learn React or something else, to make the site more ease to GET database

Comment: Don't get disheartened! Programming at the beginning is all about persistence, trail and error- and alot of `console.log()` and `print()` statements! Just take it line by line and read the error messages closely looking for line numbers and keywords